# Background Color Não aparece em site com imagem de background

Tags: html, css, background-color

estou criando este site mas logo de começo estou com um problemas. Defini uma imagem como background e agora os background das divs não aparecem. Quando é um fundo estático aparece normal, mas com imagem de fundo o background da div não aparece. alguém pode me explicar qual o problema?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>

    <div class="box">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    border: none;
    background-image: url('brackground.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.box
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: se esse CSS é copiado e colado do que você tem, está faltando abrir uma chave depois de `.box`.

Comment: `.box
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #fff;
}` a seguir ao `.box` falta um `{`

Comment: Eu já corrigi mas mesmo assim a box não aparece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem que alterar o selector univeral `*` (que engloba todos) para o `body` por exemplo, caso contrário usando `*` o `background-image` ira sobrepor-se ao `background-color`

```css
body {
  border: none;
  background-image: url('https://placehold.it/400');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box {
  width: 100px; /* alterado para o demo */
  height: 100px; /* alterado para o demo */
  background-color: red; /* alterado para o demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

O peso do seletor * é maior que o do seletor de classe, oque vai fazer com que o background definido no seletor de classe .box, seja sobreposto. Para que o background da DIV funcione, remova o * e tente colocar outro seletor, pode ser body ou até mesmo uma outra classe.

Comment: esta errado. nao tem a ver com o "peso" ou seja especificidade, neste caso a especificidade do `.box` é maior que a do `*`.

Comment: valeu pessoal, entendi agora. funciou sim! :D